# SED Replace with Slashes and Words

Tags: linux, unix, sed, command

I am trying to replace a particular command. **CDBFILELOCATION** to **+DATAC1/vbmtmdppg/** but it doesn't seem to be working. I saw some reference but all they have give is a blank slash example which is hard to understand. Please find the command i am using right now.

```
sed -i 's/CDBFILELOCATION/+DATAC1/vbmtmdppg/g' /u01/app/oracle/admin/vbmtmdpp/cr_db/mtmp_plug_pdb.sql
```

I get the error below
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the `/` in the replacement string:

```
sed -i 's/CDBFILELOCATION/+DATAC1\/vbmtmdppg/g' /u01/app/oracle/admin/vbmtmdpp/cr_db/mtmp_plug_pdb.sql
```

Alternatively, you can use a different delimiter in place of `/`:

```
sed -i 's|CDBFILELOCATION|+DATAC1/vbmtmdppg|g' /u01/app/oracle/admin/vbmtmdpp/cr_db/mtmp_plug_pdb.sql
```

Comment: I always knew that escaping the text was the option but i didn't know how to associate it. Thanks for elaborating it.